# Does reproducing a chat stream violate the ToS?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat

If I wanted to demo my websocket client/server functionality by programmatically consuming a chat stream from one of the stackoverflow rooms and subsequently re-broadcasting the feed on another site via websocket push would that be a violation of the SO/SE Terms of Service?

There's no commercial intent -- it would strictly be for demo purposes -- but I wanted to ask before I unwittingly did something naughty.

Beyond my personal use-case, I feel like this kind of question is likely to crop up more often as developers move in larger numbers to the "real-time web" all the marketing types love to reference.

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of most pages, you will see

> > user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required

There is also a link to this blog post which details what to do.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

**Edit**

In response to comments that the mentioned disclaimer is not listen on chat pages, I will refer you to the TOS.  Specifically section 3 "Subscriber Content".  The end of this section reiterates what is stated in the previously mentioned blog post.

https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service

> > In the event that You post or otherwise use Subscriber Content outside of the Network or Services, whether such Subscriber Content was created by You or others, You agree that You will follow the attribution rules of the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license as follows:

> > - You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually
> >   displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content
> >   as coming from the Stack Exchange Network. This requirement is
> >   satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but
> >   clear visual indication.

> > - You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content
> >   includes a hyperlink directly to the original question on the source
> >   site on the Network (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)

> > - You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually
> >   display or otherwise clearly indicate the author names for every
> >   question and answer so used.

> > - You will ensure that any such Internet use of Subscriber Content
> >   Hyperlink each author name directly back to his or her user profile
> >   page on the source site on the Network (e.g.,
> >   https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username), directly to the Stack
> >   Exchange domain, in standard HTML (i.e. not through a Tinyurl or
> >   other such indirect hyperlink, form of obfuscation or redirection),
> >   without any “nofollow” command or any other such means of avoiding
> >   detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript
> >   disabled.

Comment: That is absolutely correct, but I wonder if that applies to the chat.

Comment: The first line of the blog is "All the content contributed to Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow Meta....".  I would assume that chat is included in "All the content".

Comment: @cadrell0 Then again the chat pages feature no such disclaimer at the bottom, nor a link to the CC-BY-SA information, unless I'm overlooking it.

Comment: @Bart you are correct.  I've updated my answer to include info from the SE global TOS.

Comment: I'm still not sure about this. All of references in the TOS discuss "questions" and "answers" ...

Comment: Another issue with this ... websockets by definition will require javascript: how am I to satisfy this requirement: `without any "no follow" command or any such means of avoiding detection by search engines, and visible even with JavaScript disabled.`??? The content will only ever be visible to clients with javascript capabilities.

Comment: I would guess that since the Subscriber Content is being added by JavaScript, if JavaScript is disabled, then the Subscriber Content is not being used.  Therefore, there is no requirement to include links to the authors profile for the content that is not being used.